# how to fix smpt error (435) and exim config error

Tags: authentication, smtp, exim, directadmin

I have problem to use my server mail service with this error:

````
```2020-08-08 12:27:28 login authenticator failed for (User) [45.143.223.125]: 435 Unable to authenticate at present (set_id=helpdesk@compoteam.net): Undefined subroutine &main::smtpauth called.

2020-08-08 12:27:37 login authenticator failed for (User) [212.70.149.3]: 435 Unable to authenticate at present (set_id=michel@compoteam.net): Undefined subroutine &main::smtpauth called.
````

I have to note this, We gave wrong domain to our host provider to config and `(set_id=michel@compoteam.net)` is not in a correct form of our email actually  `@compoteam.net` is not correct it should be `@compexteam.ir`.

Because of this i think exim did not config correctly.

how can i fix this.

Im using direct admin.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you got the newest exim.pl file? try to update exim.pl and check your sending limits in /etc/virtual/limit (or limit_login)
Also check if /etc/virtual/compoteam.net/passwd exists for virtual mailboxes